# Mirror another program's screen in a window's program

Tags: c#, windows, winui-3

I want to build a window's 11 application that takes another program and mirrors its screen in another window. something akin to the crop and lock function in microsoft powertoys. I am building the program using the WinUI 3 Library and C# which is what is used in the mentioned program.

If anyone could lead me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

i researched and found that bitblt might be a good option but i am not sure of the steps and i also feel like there is a better solution

Comment: Search by DWM Thumbnail.

Comment: Powertoys is open source https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/blob/main/src/modules/CropAndLock/CropAndLock/ThumbnailCropAndLockWindow.cpp DwmRegisterThumbnail (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/thumbnail-ovw) is at center. C# example https://gist.github.com/abodalevsky/f97ecd3e720d7f286cf52edb697e69b3

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Or may you mean [Screen capture](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/tree/master/cpp/ScreenCaptureforHWND)?